# Can´t solve 403 Forbidden Error [nginx - windows]

Tags: windows, nginx, http-status-code-403

I tried several times to solve my problem but I didn´t find any solution for my problem!

I can visit my website from my vps but if i try it from my local computer I get a 403 Error!

It would be nice if anyone can help me!

PS: I don´t want to show the files with autoindex!!!

My nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        #charset koi8-r;


        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.php;
            allow    all;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;

        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server

   server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate      localhost.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  localhost.key;

        #ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    }


}
```

Comment: What do you type in address bar of you browser to get to this site? localhost?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Run as administrator fixed this problem for me.

I have the same problem. installed nginix using Chocolatey. This installs nginx as services too.
After facing this problem I stoped the services and started nginx as administrator.
Just right click the exe file and choose Run As Adminstrator.